# in python SKLearn LogisticRegression, is there a way to split the predict_proba(X) method?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have created a LogisticRegression in python with the SKLearn module, which predicts a binary class [0, 1]. This prediction is based on a dataset with 18 columns.
With the predict(x) function you can get the probability of a row belonging to either one of the classes.

My question is:
Is there a way to get how much a column affected the probability?

For example:

The Logistic Regression is based on a table with the columns [diabetes, weight, smoking, drinking]

With the predict_proba(x) method I receive the result, that the person in the first row has a 0.7 probability of having diabetes.

I would like to know how much of that 0.7 is due to the weight, smoking and drinking individually.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Library `shap` is maybe what you are asking for. Take a look [here](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/tabular_examples/linear_models/Sentiment%20Analysis%20with%20Logistic%20Regression.html)